# how can we add user defined settings in xcode 9 while we are making a framework

Tags: ios, swift, variables, frameworks, xcode9

I am making a framework and I want to add a user defined variable to its settings. I am using xcode 9, but the option for adding the user defines settings is disabled. Is there any way possible to add the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't as Settings.bundle must be unique per app installation, the only thing you can do is prepare your framework for process the need settings and externally to your framework provide a sample *.plist with the default settings as an example.